# anchor tag is larger than element it holds

Tags: html, css

On my website I have two images/buttons called Get Started and Learn More. The images are wrapped with an anchor tag to take you to separate pages. However, the clickable area is much larger then the actual image. And I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<!--button Holder-->
<div class="d-all m-all" id="buttonHolder">
    <div class="d4-d6 m-all" id="getStarted">
        <a href="contact.html#contactFormContainer"><img id="getStartedButton" src="images/get_started_button_vi.jpg" height="52"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="d7-d9 m-all" id="learnMore">
        <a href="services.html"><img id="learnMoreButton" src="images/learn_more__button_vi.jpg" height="52" ></a>
    </div>
   <div class="m-all d-all">
       <hr class="hrBreakTop"/>
   </div>
</div><!--End button holder-->
```

CSS

```
/*Buttons*/
#buttonHolder{

}
    #buttonHolder img{
        margin-top:155px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        display:block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    /*Reduce button sizes on mobile*/
    @media all and (min-width:451px) and (max-width: 989px){
        #buttonHolder img{
            margin-top:65px;
            width:45%;
            display:block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            height:auto;
        }

    } 
    /*Reduce padding top on mobile*/
    @media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 450px){
        #buttonHolder img{
            margin-top:0px;
        }

    } 


    #getStarted{

    }
        #getStartedButton{
            margin-right:20px;
        }
        /*Add top margin to button to prevent merging with VoipInnovations middle logo*/
        @media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
            #getStartedButton{
                margin-top:15px;
            }
        } 

    #learnMore{

    }
        #learnMoreButton{
            margin-left:20px;
        }
```

Comment: apply the css styles to the `a` containing the `img` rather than the `img` themselves. `a.some_class { margin-top: 155px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its caused by the margins you have on the images in the links. You want to move the margins to the anchor tags

```
#buttonHolder a {
display: block;
margin: 155px auto 10px;
width: 226px;
}
```

And give the images no margin

```
#buttonHolder img {
display: block;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: While what your saying makes sense, I tried it and it didnt work.

Comment: This did work. I pulled a bonehead move and tried refreshing my backup of the page instead of the one i was working on. Thank for your help!

Answer (score 8):

For me it helped to make the image `display:block`. The reason why it cannot be inline is (i heard) the white-space reserved for characters that go bellow the line like "y".

Comment: stumbled over this thread in search of accurately this solution. Since the OP has found a different solution helpful, I don't think it solves his problem. I found this thread, having the right question for this answer, so I upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

just set float:left property on image like this and your problem will be solved

```
#buttonHolder img {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: yes.works for me.check in firebug.just append float:left; and it works fine.

Comment: While it fixes the clickable area problem, it causes my image to not center align. At least in Chrome